# Como eu Posso fazer essa div desaparecer?

Tags: html

Eu sou iniciante, e estou criando um site pessoal.
Nele, quero colocar um estilo de `modal` com um produto para compra.
Consegui achar algo que pelo menos se parece com um `modal`, mas estou tendo problemas.

Queria que esse modal só aparecesse no botão "Buy Single" (é um site de venda de músicas).

E também, que tivesse dentro desse modal um botão fechar, para o usuário abrir e fechar quando quisesse.

Já procurei, mas não funcionou.

Esse é um exemplo de `modal` (Coloquei um vídeo dentro, é onde estará o conteúdo.):

```
<table width="280" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" border="0" bgcolor="#1E679A">
<tr>
   <div id="1"><td bgcolor="#fff" style="padding: 25px 50px; border-radius: 5px;  position: fixed; 
  right: 300px; 
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index:10;"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fdiJ2y7m2tY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </td></div>
</tr>
</table>
```

Por favor, me ajudem.
Preciso mesmo desse efeito, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Onde está o exemplo? Mostre algum código para mostrar o que já conseguiu.

Comment: Ali está ele. É Apenas o Modal. Mas o que eu quero é controlar quando ele aparece e desaparece com botões.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando `CSS`, com o [`Bootstrap`](http://getbootstrap.com/).

[Neste link](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-modals.php) tem um tutorial sobre como implementar (em inglês), e abaixo segue um exemplo verificável que tentei adequar a sua situação. Clique em "Executar trecho de código" e depois em "Página toda" abaixo (porque o botão de fechar fica ocultado pelo "Página toda").

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".btn").click(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
 });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
     margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Buy Single</a>
    
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmar compra</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fdiJ2y7m2tY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>
</div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: É Algo deste tipo que eu procuro, mas infelizmente, não funcionou no meu site: www.hugovales.esy.es

Comment: Hugo, este é um exemplo, você precisa seguir o tutorial pra aprender a implementar no seu site. Dei uma olhada no código do seu site, e parece que tem  algumas inconsistências. E você incluiu desde o `title` até os links de `css` e `javascript` do `modal` (os específicos) no meio das `divs`. Neste caso tem que incluir os links entre as tags `head` e o `title` pode apagar). Tente utilizar uma IDE para identificar onde os problemas, inspecionando com o navegador pra ajudar. Qualquer coisa, pode postar outra pergunta com aquilo que estiver dando problema.

Comment: Eu achei um tutorial e estou experimentando. O Meu Site está sendo feito com um construtor de sites. Eu tinha conseguido fazer o efeito fechar a div com botão antes, mas agora não consigo mais porque eu recomecei com um design novo. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faço assim usando `Jquery` tem alguns exemplo neste [link](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message). É um efeito elegante e você só precisa se preocupar com o conteúdo que está dentro da janela.

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal message</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#dialog-message").hide();//Esconde dialog message para não exibir ao carregar pagina.
    });

   //Função exibi dialogo modal
   function exibirModal() {
       $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({modal: true});
   };
   </script>

</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="exibirModal()">Exibir modal</button>

    <!-- DIV CONTEM O CONTEUDO DA JANELA MODAL-->
    <div id="dialog-message" title="Minha janela de dialogo">
        <p>Hello World!!</p>
    </div> 

</body>
</html>
```